# Как выполнить функцию после того, как будет переменная получит своё значение через fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Каждому элементу массива "contents" (в цикле) присваивается то значение, которое приходит через fetch-запрос. Как сделать так, чтобы следующая за этим циклом функция начинала работать только после того, как будет выполнен цикл и все элементы массива "contents" получат своё значение?

```
function setContents() {
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        contents[i] = getContent(list[i].link)
    }
    nextFunction() // Выполняется преждевременно, когда contents ещё "не готов"
}

async function getContent(link) {
    let response = await fetch('/folder/' + link + '.json')
    contents1[i] = await response.json()
}
```

Этот вопрос решается через вызов *следующей функции* через указанное время, но нужно, чтобы выполнение происходило "как только, так сразу".

```
setTimeout('nextFunction()', 10000)
```

Comment: async/await, не?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать `async`/`await` в функции, где вы **вызываете** функцию `getContent`. В самой функции `getContent` это необязательно.

То есть, в вашем случае можно сделать так:

```js
async function setContents() {
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        contents[i] = await getContent(list[i].link)
    }
    nextFunction() // Будет выполняться после того, как цикл закончится и все значения будут получены
}

function getContent(link) {
    let response = await fetch('/folder/' + link + '.json')
    contents1[i] = await response.json()
}
```

Заметьте, `await` вызывается не перед `contents[i] =` , а перед `getContent(...)`.

В этом случае, JavaScript будет ждать выполнения функции `await getContent()`, а не оставит её выполняться синхронно в итерации цикла `for`.

Для этого случая, я составил небольшой пример, и сам убедился, что это работает:

```js
function nextFunction() {
    console.log("Следующая функция"); // Это будет выводиться ПОСЛЕ того, как цикл закончится
}

// Для корректной работы тут необходим async
async function iterateCycle() {
    // Тут надо вставить число итераций, необходимое вам
    //             ^^^
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // А вот тут необходимо вставить await перед вызовом функции
        console.log(await oneIteration(i)); //-->1 итерация
                                            //-->2 итерация
                                            //   и т.д.
    }
    nextFunction(); // Будет выполняться после завершения цикла for
}

// Заметьте, тут необязательны операторы async/await
function oneIteration(iteration) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // Будет возвращаться каждую итерацию через 1 секунду после вызова функции
       setTimeout(() => {
           resolve(iteration + " итерация.");
       }, 1000);
    });
}

// В конце концов, вызываем цикл
iterateCycle();
```

Comment: Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать так, чтобы следующая за этим циклом функция начинала работать только после того, как будет выполнен цикл и все элементы массива "contents" получат своё значение?

Например можно использовать асинхронность более "широко" - вот таким образом...

```js
function setContents() {
  const a = []
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    a.push(getContent(list[i].link, i))
  }
  Promise.all(a)
    .then(_ => nextFunction())
    .catch(console.error)
}

async function getContent(link, i) {
  let response = await fetch('/folder/' + link + '.json')
  contents1[i] = await response.json()
}
```